# Number of spaces change when hitting Tab in inline comments

Tags: vim

I have the below settings in my`.vimrc` for Python dev environment:

```
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set autoindent
```

Sometimes at the end of the line when I hit `Tab` to add inline comments, the number of spaces is not 4, but less than that. I am not able to figure out the pattern yet, but I think it depends on line length.

This is how it looks in my editor:

[image]

How can I make sure that the number of spaces stays consistent?

Comment: once you start "inline tabbing" the initial tab will tab out to a integer divisor of your specified tab width.

Comment: Tab does not mean "insert N spaces", it means "fill with spaces to  the next multiple of N columns".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it' intended behaviour, because with this behavior the tab stops align over multiple lines. See for example line 5 and 7.